# can i access the variable declared in main in any function?

Tags: c++, function, class, variables

i have two files

```
 books.cpp and books.h
```

i am using these classes in my main function.
i also have a function *func* in main.cpp file.

```
#include iostream
#include "books.h"
void func(int a, int b);
int main(){
    books book;
    func(5,6);
    return 0;
}

void func(int a, int b){
   //can i use the book object declared in main in this function?
}
```

i want the books class object book declared in main in the function how can i access it?
can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly.  You will have to pass it in to your function or make it global.

```
void func(int a, int b, books book)
{
    // use me
}
```

Comment: That'll be a different object.

Comment: thanks =) will try this. is there some difference between global and extern variables?

Comment: @sara: extern is a keyword to access a (global) variable declared in another .c(pp) file

Comment: @LoztInSpace: add reference for books ;)

Comment: @MichałWalenciak thanks working after passing by reference =)